# anyone know how to make a flatlist reset id number after I remove 1 item from it

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-flatlist

like my title said I struggle with this though below is a example

```
{ id: '1', name: 'one' },
    { id: '2', name: 'two' },
    { id: '3', name: 'three' },
    { id: '4', name: 'four' },
```

this is a flatlist after I remove item with id '2' I want id 3 become 2 and id 4 become 3 so the flatlist after id 2 be removed will like

```
{ id: '1', name: 'one' },
        { id: '2', name: 'three' },
        { id: '3', name: 'four' },
```

here is my code

```
export default function Listdata({ route }) {
    const [itemData, newItem] = React.useState([]);

    const [itemState, setItemState] = React.useState(itemData);
    const [idmoi, incr,] = React.useState(1);
    const [textNhapVao, setTextNhapVao] = React.useState('');


    const tinhToanId = (t) => {
        var idNew = [itemData.id];
        incr(idNew - 1);
    }


    const themItem = () => {
        var arrayMoi = [...itemData, { id: idmoi, name: textNhapVao }];
        incr(idmoi + 1)
        console.log('idddd')
        console.log(idmoi)
        setItemState(arrayMoi);
        newItem(arrayMoi);
    }
    <View>

    </View>

    const keyboardVerticalOffset = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 40 : 0

    const xoaItem = (IItem) => {
        console.log('routeeee')
        console.log(route.params.paramKey)
        setItemState(prevItemState => prevItemState.filter((_item, _Index) => _Index !== IItem));
    }
    return (
        <Container style={styles.container}>
            <View style={{
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                borderBottomWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#d7d7d7',
            }}>
                <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 30, color: 'green' }}>Xin Chào {route.params.paramKey}</Text>
            </View>
            <FlatList
                data={itemState}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                        <View style={{ marginLeft: 20 }}>
                            <Text style={{ fontSize: 30, color: 'red' }} >{item.id}{'\n'}{item.name}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', marginRight: 20 }}>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                style={{
                                    width: '100%',
                                    backgroundColor: 'red',
                                }}
                                activeOpacity={0.7}
                                onPress={() => xoaItem(index)}
                            >
                                <IconFE name='trash-2' size={30} style={{ color: 'orange' }} />
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                )}
            />
            <View
                style={{
                    position: 'relative', height: 50,
                    borderTopWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: '#d7d7d7',
                }}>
                <KeyboardAvoidingView enabled behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : null} keyboardVerticalOffset={keyboardVerticalOffset} >
                    <View
                        style={{
                            alignItems: 'center', position: 'relative',
                            flexDirection: 'row',
                            justifyContent: 'space-between',
                            marginLeft: 20,
                            marginRight: 20,
                        }}>
                        <Input
                            onChangeText={data => setTextNhapVao(data)}
                            placeholder='Nhập Vào Đây'></Input>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            title="Thêm"
                            onPress={themItem}>
                            <IconFE name='check-square' size={30} style={{ color: 'blue' }} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
            </View>
        </Container>
    )
}
```

and below is my screenshot flatlist: https://uphinh.org/image/9OLoCN

Comment: what have you tried? please add your code as well.

Comment: Is your input an array of objects?

Comment: @NinaScholz i trying make flatlist with some button to remove item of flatlist it like this https://uphinh.org/image/9OLoCN also wait I gonna up code too

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath I will up code wait

Comment: @NinaScholz  I edited plzz check

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath I edited plzz check

Comment: Hi, please avoid noise phrases in your posts like "sorry for my english" or "please help". Not everyone here is a native English speaker and it's obvious that you're looking for help. No need to restate that.

Comment: @georg Hi, George thank u I gonna remember it next time post question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a function which removes the object at the given index.

The function takes the removed array, takes the object at start and gets the `id` then it loops from the index until the end and updates all `id` properties.

```js
const
    remove = (array, index) => {
        let removed = array.splice(index, 1);

        if (!removed.length) return array;
        let id = +removed[0].id;
        while (index < array.length) array[index++].id = (id++).toString();
        return array;
    },
    data = [{ id: '1', name: 'one' }, { id: '2', name: 'two' }, { id: '3', name: 'three' },  { id: '4', name: 'four' }];

remove(data, 1);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: that seem amazing but how about use foreach ?  I kinda suck at loot :C

Comment: btw thank you I gonna try it if it work I will mark as answer

Comment: @NguyễnHoàngSơn, `forEach` iterates the whole array, but you need only a part to iterate.

Comment: hey man I tried it but my app said undefined not an object 'array.splice(index,1)[0].id'

Comment: does the index exists in the array? maybe you need to check the index in advance ...

Comment: hmm.. I will check again

Comment: @Nini Scholz can u make an expo plzz

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your `id` is not continues (`1,2,3...`), because if so, you don't need to mutate `id` at all, you can just use `array` indices instead. Anyway, if you assume that `id` is not continues, we can try following algorithm:

- Find remove index,
- Map element `n` to `n+1` for indices higher than remove index,
- Remove last element (it will be our final remove item, that has been pushed to the end).

Code example:

```js
const data = [
    { id: '1', name: 'one' },
    { id: '2', name: 'two' },
    { id: '5', name: 'five' },
    { id: '6', name: 'six' }]
    
    
const removeFromArr = (arr, name) => {
  const removeIdx = arr.findIndex(e => e.name === name)
  return arr.map((e, i, a) => removeIdx <= i ? ({...e, name: a?.[i + 1]?.name}) : e) // map element n to n+1 if higher than remove idx
            .slice(0, arr.length - 1) // remove last item
}
 
const newData = removeFromArr(data, "two")
 
console.log(newData)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: ty I will try it

Answer (score 1):

From the provided array remove the selected array by splice method by finding its index

Working example: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/137768

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, Image, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions, FlatList} from 'react-native';

export default class SupervisorDashboard extends Component<Props> {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      userData:[
                {id:1, name:"One"},
                {id:2, name:"Two"},
                {id:3, name:"Three"},
                {id:4, name:"Four"},
                {id:5, name:"Five"},
                {id:6, name:"Six"},
              ]
      
     
    }    
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    
  }


  removeItem(index){
    this.state.userData.splice(index, 1);
    var array = []
    // console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.userData))
    for(var i=0; i< this.state.userData.length; i++){
      var eachElement = {id: (i+1), name: this.state.userData[i].name }
      array.push(eachElement)
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(array)) 

    this.setState({}) 
  }

  renderItem(item, index){
    // console.log(item.id) 
    return(
      <View style={{height:60, width:'90%', marginTop:10, marginLeft:'5%', marginRight:'5%', flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'space-between', alignItems:'center', borderRadius:10, borderWidth:1, borderColor:'#ececec', padding:10}}>
        <Text>{item.id}</Text>
        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{this.removeItem(index)}} style={{marginRight:10, backgroundColor:'grey', height:'100%', justifyContent:"center", borderRadius:10, padding:10}}>
            <Text>Click to remove</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
 
  
  render(){
    return(
      <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'white'}}>
                <FlatList
                data={this.state.userData}
                renderItem={({ item, index })=>this.renderItem(item, index)}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
              />
        
      </View>
    );
  }

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  background: {
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  }
});
```

Comment: ty I will try it

Comment: hmm I tried ur expo and it can remove item but it won't reset the id like I want

Comment: You have to reposition the id of each element after removing the element
Updated the example. You can check now

Comment: how I can reposition the id ? I tried ur expo but It still go like 1, 4, 5, 6 ....

Comment: Check the example i have updated it https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/137768

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this result

- Find the index of the element that you want to remove using [findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)
- Then divide the array into two halves
- Add one to the second array after it is parsed to `int`.
- join the array.
- Be sure to cover the corner case if the element is not in `arr`.

```js
const arr = [
  { id: "1", name: "one" },
  { id: "2", name: "two" },
  { id: "3", name: "three" },
  { id: "4", name: "four" },
];

function resetIds(arr) {
  return arr.map((o) => {
    return { ...o, id: `${parseInt(o.id) - 1}` };
  });
}

const id = "2";
const elementToRemoveIndex = arr.findIndex((o) => o.id === id);

const result =
  elementToRemoveIndex !== -1
    ? [
        ...arr.slice(0, elementToRemoveIndex),
        ...resetIds(arr.slice(elementToRemoveIndex + 1)),
      ]
    : [...arr];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: thank you I gonna try it if it work I will mark as answer

Comment: I couldn't understand if someone downvote, at least tell me the reason. So that I can improve.

Comment: yeah I saw u got downvote so I make upvote back to u